# Cereal serialization error

Tags: c++, serialization, save, glm-math, cereal

So i'm legit confused. It won't compile for an external serialization  function. It gives the error

> cereal could not find any output serialization functions for the
>   provided type and archive combination.

So the code below doesn't compile

```
#include <fstream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "SceneObject.h"
#include <cereal/cereal.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/json.hpp>

template<typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& archive, glm::vec3& v3)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", v3.x), cereal::make_nvp("y", v3.y), cereal::make_nvp("z", v3.z));
}

struct something
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
};
template<typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& archive, something& v3)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", v3.x), cereal::make_nvp("y", v3.y), cereal::make_nvp("z", v3.z));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SceneObject test;
    test.transform().setPosition(1.0f,2.0f,3.0f);

    {
        std::ofstream file("TestPath.json");
        cereal::JSONOutputArchive output(file);
        glm::vec3 p = test.transform().getPosition();
        output(p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but this DOES compile

```
#include <fstream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "SceneObject.h"
#include <cereal/cereal.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/json.hpp>

template<typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& archive, glm::vec3& v3)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", v3.x), cereal::make_nvp("y", v3.y), cereal::make_nvp("z", v3.z));
}

struct something
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
};
template<typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& archive, something& v3)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", v3.x), cereal::make_nvp("y", v3.y), cereal::make_nvp("z", v3.z));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SceneObject test;
    test.transform().setPosition(1.0f,2.0f,3.0f);

    {
        std::ofstream file("TestPath.json");
        cereal::JSONOutputArchive output(file);
        glm::vec3 p = test.transform().getPosition();
        something s;
        s.x = p.x;
        s.y = p.y;
        s.z = p.z;
        output(s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I literally copy and pasted the save code from glm::vec3 to something and just changed glm::vec3 to 'something'. It makes NO sense to me why it would work for one and not the other. I think it might be a namespace thing, but I have no clue how to fix that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well apparently posting made me find the solution.

You need to make sure the serialize functions share the same namespace so if I wrap them like

```
namespace glm
{
template<typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& archive, glm::vec3& v3)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", v3.x), cereal::make_nvp("y", v3.y),    cereal::make_nvp("z", v3.z));
}
}
```

It works. Kinda odd, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm your conclusion. in case of externally defined serialize-functions you would place them in the same namespace to enable cereal to see/use them.

a complete/templated set of serialization-functions for all flavors of vec2-4, mat2-4 and quat types can be achieved like this (requires glm-version >=0.9.6, https://www.g-truc.net/post-0693.html):

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <cereal/cereal.hpp>

namespace glm
{

template<class Archive, class T>
void serialize(Archive &archive, glm::vec<2, T, glm::defaultp> &v)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", v.x),
            cereal::make_nvp("y", v.y));
}

template<class Archive, class T>
void serialize(Archive &archive, glm::vec<3, T, glm::defaultp> &v)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", v.x),
            cereal::make_nvp("y", v.y),
            cereal::make_nvp("z", v.z));
}

template<class Archive, class T>
void serialize(Archive &archive, glm::vec<4, T, glm::defaultp> &v)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", v.x),
            cereal::make_nvp("y", v.y),
            cereal::make_nvp("z", v.z),
            cereal::make_nvp("w", v.w));
}

// glm matrices serialization
template<class Archive, class T>
void serialize(Archive &archive, glm::mat<2, 2, T, glm::defaultp> &m){ archive(m[0], m[1]); }

template<class Archive, class T>
void serialize(Archive &archive, glm::mat<3, 3, T, glm::defaultp> &m){ archive(m[0], m[1], m[2]); }

template<class Archive, class T>
void serialize(Archive &archive, glm::mat<4, 4, T, glm::defaultp> &m){ archive(m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3]); }

template<class Archive, class T>
void serialize(Archive &archive, glm::qua<T, glm::defaultp> &q)
{
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("x", q.x),
            cereal::make_nvp("y", q.y),
            cereal::make_nvp("z", q.z),
            cereal::make_nvp("w", q.w));
}

}// namespace glm
```